# SQL Query: Where datetime = past 24 hours, how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

```
select eventdatetime, eventid, sCode, sNarrative
FROM [Blue Prism].dbo.BPAAuditEvents;
```

eventdatetime type is datetime.

I need to create a query to return these columns, where eventdatetime = the last 24 hours.

How can I do this?

I've tried a bunch of queries but I'm not having any luck.

1) `WHERE DATE(eventdatetime) = DATE(NOW())`

This returned a syntax error

> SQL Error [195] [S00010]: 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

2) `where convert(varchar(10), eventdatetime, 102) 
    = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)`

This returned no data, but also no errors.

3) `WHERE CAST(eventdatetime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

This also returned no data, but also no errors.

```
select eventdatetime, eventid, sCode, sNarrative
FROM [Blue Prism].dbo.BPAAuditEvents;
```

I expect the output to be records where eventdatetime <= 24 hours from when the query was ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`dateadd` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to *add* -24 hours to *now* ([`getdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) and then compare that to your `eventdatetime` column e.g.

```
select eventdatetime, eventid, sCode, sNarrative
from [Blue Prism].dbo.BPAAuditEvents
where eventdatetime > dateadd(hour, -24, getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

By last 24 hours, I assume that you mean any date time that falls between current time and 24 hours prior.

```sql
select eventdatetime
     , eventid
     , sCode
     , sNarrative
  from [Blue Prism].dbo.BPAAuditEvents;
 where eventdatetime > dateadd(day,-1,current_timestamp)
```

[More examples](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-dateadd-function/)

Answer (score 0):

there is several SQL functions you can use like this:

```
NOW() 2019-08-05 15:13:00
SYSDATETIME() 2019-08-05 13:10:02.0474381
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()2019-08-05 13:10:02.0474381 -07:00
SYSUTCDATETIME() 2019-08-05 20:10:02.0474381
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 2019-08-05 13:10:02.047 +
GETDATE() 2019-08-05 13:10:02.047 
GETUTCDATE() 2019-08-05 20:10:02.047
CURDATE() 2019-08-05
CURTIME() 13:10:02.047
```

the query is like @Dale Burrell post:

```
select eventdatetime, eventid, sCode, sNarrative
from [Blue Prism].dbo.BPAAuditEvents
where eventdatetime > dateadd(hour, -24, [SQL function]);
```

or

```
select eventdatetime, eventid, sCode, sNarrative
from [Blue Prism].dbo.BPAAuditEvents
where eventdatetime >= dateadd([timetype], [timevalue], [SQL function])
  and eventdatetime < dateadd([timetype], [timevalue], [SQL function]);
```

in the first script you may use `>=` so it would take exactly equal last 24 hour and bigger, or only use `>` only bigger last for 24 hours.
And then you only need change the functions as your requirement need.

the second one is for particular time. Also like the first one, you can change between `>=` or `>`

> [timetype] : minute, hour, day, month, year
>
> [timevalue] : number value you need